# Parse.com android app case insensitive searches

Tags: android, search, parse-platform

I'm using parse backend for one of my apps. There are three tables and I want to be able to search text entered by the user in search view in the table columns.

```
private void getDataFromParse() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Message.NAME);
    query.addDescendingOrder(Message.CREATED_AT);
    **query.whereStartsWith(Message.MESSAGE, mTag);**
    query.setLimit(20);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                mMessages = (List<Message>) (Object) objects;
                setAdapter();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that parse search is case sensitive. I enter the table content in parse from their websites UI. One suggestion to solve this problem is here
http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/

How do solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the text enterd by the user to upper case  and make sure that all the data in parse are upper case too

Comment: I want the string value in the column to be searchable too ! How to get that ?